# How to solve my code dependent dropdown without extentions

Tags: php, html, json, yii2

I couldn't choose the Id City when I was chose Id Province. How to solve this ?

**This code for controller**

[image: This code for controller]

**This code for view**

[image: The last this code for view]

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Please do not post images of code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post code, not pictures of code

Comment: Share your code not images :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZepxKw8VA7w). Below is my code. Hope this can help you.

**In view**

```
<div class='col-lg-4'>
            <?= $form->field($modelsBahagian, 'bahagian_id')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(TblBahagian::find()->all(), 'bahagian_id', 'bahagian_nama'),
            [
                'prompt'=>'Pilih Bahagian',
                'onchange'=>'
                    $.post("index.php?r=tbl-moderator/lists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                        $( "select#tblbhgnmod-unit_id" ).html( data );
                    });'
            ]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-4'>
            <?= $form->field($modelsBahagian, 'unit_id')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(TblUnit::find()->all(),'unit_id','unit_nama'),
                ['prompt'=>'Sila Pilih unit']
            ) ?>
        </div>
```

**In Controller**

```
public function actionLists($id)
{
    $countUnits = TblUnit::find()
        ->where(['bahagian_id' => $id])
        ->count();

    $units = TblUnit::find()
        ->where(['bahagian_id' => $id])
        ->all();

    if($countUnits > 0) {

        foreach($units as $unit){
            echo "<option value='".$unit->unit_id."'>".$unit->unit_nama."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option> - </option>";
    }
}
```